# Android : How to share layout+drawable resources between packages?

Tags: android, resources, themes

I'd like to be able to change the UI layout of an activity, based on a layout (+ it's own drawables) provided by another package (plugin theme). That's something really new to me, and I need some directions.

I already know that resources id cannot be shared, but assuming we managed to inflate the root view, we could retrieve the widgets by using the [findViewWithTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resources can be shared in lib. See [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html) link 
maybe now you can change your strategy